# Can catkin_make_isolated resume rather than restart

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [kinetic Installation OSX Homebrew Source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) guide, which has some hick-ups.  I'm fixing each problem as it comes along, but when I run the `catkin_make_isolated` each time, catkin make starts processing from the start and it takes a long time before it gets to the problem I'm trying to fix.

Is there a way of invoking `catkin_make_isolated` such that it continues where it's up to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343645/can-catkin_make_isolated-resume-rather-than-restart/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2020-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from looking at the help: `catkin_make_isolated -h`:

```
--from-pkg PKGNAME      Restart catkin_make_isolated at the given package
                        continuing from there (do not change CMake arguments,
                        add/move/remove packages or toggle the install flag
                        when using this option since this may result in an
                        inconsistent workspace state).
```

This looks like the option you are looking for

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2